# Getting the value of a super class field

Tags: java, inheritance

In the following code, `super.type` brings the value of `this.type`.

```
// http://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=303&p_certName=SQ1Z0_803

class Feline {
    public String type = "f ";
    public void hh(){ System.out.print("FFFFF ");}
}


public class Cougar extends Feline {
    public void hh(){ 
        super.hh();
        this.type = "c ";
        System.out.print("CCCCC "+this.type + super.type);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { new Cougar().hh(); }

}
```

How can i get the value of `super.type` in the descendant class ?

TIA.

Comment: Since you are extending `Feline` class, You override `type` value by assigning `c`.If you create it in subclass then you will get your desire String value using `super.type`.

Comment: Do not accept so quickly. It is not at all clear what you're trying to accomplish, and the answer you accepted is "wrong" from an Object Oriented perspective.  It is very rare that shadowing a superclass member is the correct thing to do, and this will break other peoples' expectations of how class hierarchies behave.  You need to clarify the behavior you are getting and what you are expecting, and why you think something is wrong.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If I change the class `Cougar` to

```
public class Cougar extends Feline {
    public String type = "c "; // <-- shadow Feline's type.
    public void hh() {
        super.hh();
        // this.type = "c ";
        System.out.print("CCCCC " + this.type + super.type);
    }
}
```

Then I get the output you seem to expect of

```
FFFFF CCCCC c f
```

Instead of the output your code produces (which was)

```
FFFFF CCCCC c c
```

This is not the OO way to do things, because `Cougar` [**is-a**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) `Feline`. The behaviour you see (of the value changing in the super class) is because of that relationship. Finally, to keep the values distinct you would need to shadow the `Feline` type as above.

Answer (score 2):

`public String type = "f "` is exist in your super class. So it is get inherited to your child class. When you call `this.type = "c"` What it does is changed the value of type variable which exist in super class. So the output that you are getting is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You just create one Cougar instance, at begining, type field is "f", however, before you print super.type, you have had re-assigned value "c" to it.

You can figure it out with following code:

```
class Feline {
    public String type = "f ";
    public void hh(){ System.out.print(type);}
}


public class Cougar extends Feline {
    public void hh(){ 
        super.hh();
        this.type = "c ";
        System.out.print(this.type + super.type);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { new Cougar().hh(); }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
How can i get the value of super.type in the descendant class ?
```

**problem:**

```
this.type = "c "; //this.type will return the super.type
```

You already referencing the value of your `super.type` to `"c "` thus printing `"c"`

**solution:**

You need to create a `type` variable in your `Cougar` class to change the scope of `this.type`.

Answer (score 0):

you overrided the value of type in class Cougar. Doing this:

```
this.type = "c ";
```

If you want have difference between super.type and this.type add field whith name type to Cougar too.

```
public class Cougar extends Feline {
    public String type = ""; //add this
    public void hh(){ 
        super.hh();
        this.type = "c ";
        System.out.print("CCCCC "+this.type + super.type);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { new Cougar().hh(); }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I can't understand you real meaning of doing this.
If you really want to diff the type, you should declare the type in Cougar:

```
public class Cougar extends Feline {
    public String type = "c ";

    ...
}
```